# Problems with Maven 3 on Windows 7

Tags: maven-3, windows-7-x64

Struggling to see if i've setup maven 3 correctly using JDK 1.7 and windows 7.

I cant get it to produce any POM file following the guide on maven. so my assumption was its not setup correctly. however, when i run mvn -version its showing the correct locations, but getting an error referencing the command prompt.

I found similar threads on here and tried lots of combinations with no joy, including adding a MVN_HOME variable.

Note sure if this would cause any problem, but i have a CLASSPATH set to look in the lib directory of axis2 from some prior work i was doing there. mentioning just in case.

any help really appreciated!

```
C:\Users\Phil Ward>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 13:51:28+0000)
Maven home: C:\Users\Phil Ward\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Phil Ward>
C:\Users\Phil Ward>
C:\Users\Phil Ward>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\User\Phil Ward\axis2-1.6.1\lib

C:\Users\Phil Ward>
C:\Users\Phil Ward>
C:\Users\Phil Ward>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\Phil Ward\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin

C:\Users\Phil Ward>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only **add** the location of Maven to your PATH variable in your case:

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Phil Ward\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
```

and **not** set the PATH to only the location of Maven like this:

```
PATH=C:\Users\Phil Ward\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin
```

because you will not be able to find commands like `cmd.exe` etc.

Comment: still no joy :(

C:\Users\Phil Ward>echo %PATH%
%PATH%;C:\Users\Phil Ward\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin

C:\Users\Phil Ward>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 13:51:28+0000)
Maven home: C:\Users\Phil Ward\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to close the command windows first. Open is newly or better go via Environment variable setting in Windows 7 and enhance the PATH.

Comment: tried that approach before and it didn't work. i justrestarted windows and suddenly its working :)